# Error en código basico c++. "Nombredelavariable" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo *C++* y el error que me aparece en *Eclipse* es:

> "Nombredelavariable" was not declared in this scope

En el **documento.h** tengo declarado la variable `m_nomLocal`, así que no sé a qué puede referirse.

En el archivo .h declaro algunas funciones y las variables:

```
#ifndef PARTIT_H
#define PARTIT_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "cadena.h"

class CPartit {
public:
    CCadena GetLocal();
    CCadena GetVisitant();
    int GetPuntsLocal();
    int GetPuntsVisitant();
private:
    int m_puntsLocal;
    int m_puntsVisitant;
    int m_puntsTotal;
    CCadena m_nomLocal;
    CCadena m_nomVisitant;
    int partit;
};

#endif
```

Y en el .cpp las defino tal que:

```
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#include "partit.h"

CCadena GetLocal()
{
    return m_nomLocal;
}
CCadena GetVisitant()
{
    return m_nomVisitant;
}
int GetPuntsLocal()
{
    return m_puntsLocal;
}
int GetPuntsVisitant()
{
    return m_puntsVisitant;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has realizado un include del fichero al principio del documento?

Comment: Diría que si, te refieres a enlazarlo a partit.h verdad? es decir #include partit.h

Comment: Creo que se refiere a si has incluido `#include "documento.h"`

Comment: @asdasdasd Sí, me refería a eso mismo.

Comment: @ElPatrón sería mas fácil responderte si mostraras algo del código en el que defines las variables, y el punto exacto en el que haces el `#include ""`.

Comment: prueba a añadir `CPartit::` entre el tipo de retorno y el nombre del metodo en tu fichero de implementacion (.cpp) algo asi: `CCadena CPartit::GetLocal()`.Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Continua diciendo lo mismo, pero sí es cierto que me quita un error que decía `symbol 'x' could not be resolved`. Gracias ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Nombredelavariable" was not declared in this scope

El error, concretamente te indica que la variable llamada `Nombredelavariable` no existe en el ámbito en que está siendo usada. Se que es una perogrullada pero es importante remarcarlo para entender el error.

Vayamos pues, paso por paso. Usaré la variable `m_nomLocal` como ejemplo, pero es aplicable a las demás.

#### ... in this scope.

En este ámbito. ¿A qué se refiere? Veamos el uso de `m_nomLocal`:

```
CCadena GetLocal()
{
    return m_nomLocal; // m_nomLocal not declared in this scope
}
```

Sabemos que `m_nomLocal` forma parte de la clase `CPartit` y sabemos que `GetLocal` es una función miembro de dicha clase, así que este código debería funcionar ¿no?.

Lo cierto es que no. Porque la función `GetLocal` que acabamos de ver no forma parte de `CPartit` si no que va por libre. En otras palabras el ámbito de `GetLocal` es el ámbito global. Si queremos que forme parte del ámbito de la clase `CPartit` debemos anteponer el ámbito de la clase al nombre de la función:

```
CCadena CPartit::GetLocal()
{
    return m_nomLocal;
}
```

Con la modificación anterior, hemos añadido la función `GetLocal` al ámbito de la clase `CPartit`.

#### ... was not declared...

No ha sido declarada. ¿A qué se refiere? Si tenemos una función del ámbito global:

```
CCadena GetLocal()
{
    return m_nomLocal;
}
```

Ésta sólo podrá acceder a funciones del mismo ámbito o ámbitos menos restrictivos. Dado que el ámbito global es el ámbito menos restrictivo de todos no podrá acceder más que a variables del ámbito global.

La variable `m_nomLocal` no pertenece al ámbito global si no que pertenece al ámbito de `CPartit`, dicho de otra manera: el nombre completo de la variable sería `CPartit::m_nomLocal` y en consecuencia no existe (no ha sido declarada) ninguna variable con el nombre `m_nomLocal` en el ámbito global.

#### Otro ejemplo

```
// Variable en ambito global.
CCadena m_nomLocal;

// Función de ambito global.
CCadena GetLocal()
{
    // Acceso a la variable global 'm_nomLocal'.
    return m_nomLocal;
}

// Función en ambito 'CPartit'.
CCadena CPartit::GetLocal()
{
    // Acceso a la 'm_nomLocal' del ámbito 'CPartit'.
    return m_nomLocal;
}
```

Vemos que aunque tenemos dos variables con el mismo nombre (`m_nomLocal`) cada función accede a diferentes variables porque cada una de las funciones pertenece a un ámbito distinto, puedes ver el ejemplo en funcionamiento <kbd>[aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PiP3Kp93nweyaCj7)</kbd>.

Como "*curiosidad*", si quisieras acceder a `m_nomLocal` global desde el ámbito de `CPartit` deberías referirte a la variable como `::m_nomLocal`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era exactamente eso y lo has explicado a la perfección!

Answer (score 2):

Imagínate que tienes que modificar el código de un compañero tuyo y te encuentras con una función tal que:

```
int func()
{
  return variable;
}
```

¿Qué información puedes sacar de este código? Las conclusiones a las que yo llegaría es que `func` es una función suelta (no pertence a ninguna clase) y que `variable` debe ser una variable estática (puesto que la función no pertenece a ninguna clase).

Pues bien, al compilador le pasará exactamente lo mismo y al buscar `variable` en la lista de variables estáticas no la va a encontrar y te mostrará el error correspondiente.

Para que el compilador sepa que `func` es una función miembro de una clase debes indicarlo añadiendo el nombre de dicha clase:

```
int MiClase::func()
{
  return variable;
}
```

Ahora el compilador entenderá que `func` es una función miembro de `MiClase`, y ahora `variable` puede ser un miembro de `MiClase` o (si `MiClase` no posee ninguna variable llamada así) una variable estática.

En tu caso las funciones deberían quedar así:

```
CCadena CPartit::GetLocal()
{
  return m_nomLocal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya se lo que te sucede amigo mio! es un error que me ha ocurrido de vez en cuando. 
tu dices en **partit.h** defino la variable `m_nomLocal`. y cuando la utilizo en **partit.cpp** me dice *que no esta definida* entonces ¿qué esta pasando?

Bueno sucede que cuando tu llamas a la variable `m_nomLocal`desde el archivo **partit.cpp** tu asumes que el compilador entiende que es parte de la clase `CPartit` porque has incluido el archivo **partit.h** en la cabecera, pero no es así. debes decirle claramente que la función pertenece a la clase `CPartit`

```
CCadena CPartit::GetLocal()
{
return m_nomLocal;
}
```

es similar a lo que pasa con las funciones pertenecientes a `std`como `std::cout`o `std::endl` etc.. y que para uno evitarse hacer eso durante todo el programa escribe arriba `using namespace std` espero que eso resuelva tu problema

Comment: Un inciso... está implementando un clase, no un espacio de nombres...

Comment: muchas gracias por la aclaratoria, ya edite la respuesta espero que así sea correcta

Comment: Ahora ya pinta mejor. Tenías eso sí un pequeño lío con las mayúsculas y minúsculas del nombre de la clase... me he tomado la libertad de arreglarlo.