# Error al implementar un TAD Punto en C++

Tags: c++

El ejercicio consiste en implementar un TAD Punto, con las operaciones abscisa (devuelve la x), ordenada (devuelve la y) y distancia (calcula la distancia entre dos puntos).

El ejercicio es sencillo y este es mi código:

archivo: punto.h

```
#ifndef PUNTO_H
#define PUNTO_H

class Punto
{
public:

    //Constructores primero
    Punto();
    //Construye un punto a (0,0)
    Punto(float x, float y);
    //Construye un punto con lo que le den

    //Operaciones

    float abscisa();
    //POST: devuelve el valor x del punto actual
    float ordenada();
    //POST devuelve el valor y del punto actual
    float distancia(Punto p1, Punto p2);
    //POST: devuelve el vector distancia p1-p2

private:

    float x_, y_;//coordenadas del punto actual

};

#endif // PUNTO_H
```

archivo: punto.cpp

```
#include "punto.h"
#include <cmath>

Punto::Punto()
{
    x_ = 0.0;
    y_ = 0.0;

}

Punto::Punto(float x, float y)
{
     x_ = x;
     y_ = y;
}

float Punto::abscisa()
{
    return x_;
}

float Punto::ordenada()
{
    return y_;
}

float Punto::distancia(Punto p1, Punto p2)
{
    float dis = sqrt(pow(2,((p1.x_) - (p2.x_))) + pow(2,((p1.y_)-(p2.y_))));

    return dis;
}
```

archivo: main.cpp **AQUÍ ME DA EL ERROR...**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "punto.h"




using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Punto s1(1.0,2.0);//Constructor dandole valores a las coordenadas
    Punto s2;// valores vacíos a las coordenadas
    float x = distancia(s1, s2);//ERROR 'distancia' was not declared in this scope
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Uso QT en linux mint para programar. 
¿Cómo se soluciona este error?

PD: Ya miré en [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54852/error-en-codigo-basico-c/54921#54921) y no es el mismo error porque yo sí tengo la función distancia en el ámbito de la clase Punto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no es lo que yo clasificaría como TAD, sino como Programación orientada a objetos (POO). La diferencia es que aquí el método es parte de la definición de la clase (en TAD están separados).

Dicho lo dicho:

1) Si tienes un punto, lo lógico es que la operación `distancia` te de la distancia a otro punto, así que solo le pasas un parámetro (el otro punto, ya que llamas al método desde el objeto punto inicial). Así pues, `float Punto::distancia(Punto otroPunto)`<sup>1</sup>.

2) Ya que es POO, los métodos se invocan como parte de un objeto. Así que la llamada sería `float x = s1.distancia(s2);`

---

<sup>1</sup>Y, si no es liarte mucho, recomendaría que usaras `float Punto::distancia(Punto &otroPunto)`; la diferencia es que al llamar a un méodo definido con la versión sin el `&` se pasa por parámetro *una nueva copia del objeto original* y con la versión con `&` se pasa *una referencia al objeto original*. En todo caso, repito, es opcional.

Comment: En efecto gracias, puse TAD porque el ejercicio estaba en ese tema, ni siquiera la asignatura toca POO. Gracias por la respuesta, bien explicado.