# Miembro de la clase "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, recursión

tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Impleméntese  el  método  int bsearch(int i,  int d,  const   T&
>   x)    de  la  clase   vector_t    que efectúa la  búsqueda    binaria recursiva   en  un  vector  ordenado,   devolviendo la  posición    del elemento    encontrado  y   -1  si  no  lo  encuentra

La clase que me dan como ayuda es esta:

```
    template <class T>
    class vector_t{
    private:
           T* v_;
           int sz_;
    public:
           vector_t(int sz);
           ~vector_t(void);
           int get_sz(void) const;
           T get_v(int pos) const;
           T& get_set_v(int pos);
    };
```

lo he cambiado
            BBR(int v[], int i, int d, int x);

```
    template<class T>

int vector_t:: bsearch (int i, int d, const T& x){


    if (i>d){

        return -1;
    }

    int medio=(i+d)/2;

    if(v_[medio]==x){
        return medio;
    }

    else if(x<v_[medio]){
        return bsearch(i,medio-1,x);
    }
    else if(x>v_[medio]){
        return bsearch(medio+1,d,x);
    }
}
```

Hice el main también:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include"SinNombre1.cpp"
    using namespace std;

    int main (void){
        vector_t<int>& tabla[10];

        tabla[0]= 50;
        int buscado=50;
        int central=0;

        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
            (tabla[i])++;
        }

        int izq= 50;
        int dch= tabla-1;

        central= bsearch(izq,dch,buscado);
    }
```

Gracias

Lo que pasa que me da errores que no entiendo:

```
In function 'int main()':
6    declaration of 'tabla' as array of references
8   'tabla' was not declared in this scope
22   'template<class T> class vector_t' used without template parameters
    In function 'int bsearch(int, int, const T&)':
32  [Error] 'v_' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: `El enunciado del método me generó muchas dudas, porque no se ha declarado como parámetro un vector sirva para hacer la llamada recursiva en los diferentes casos,o eso es lo que pone en mis apuntes`. Son métodos de una clase; se aplican al propio objeto (*instancia*) al que pertenecen. En tu caso, el contenido del vector estará en `_v`. Lo que sí encuentro que falta son métodos para añadir los valores al vector; quizás lo quieras comentar a tu profesor.

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta "¿está bien?", es demasiado opinable. Además, parte del sentido de la práctica es que compruebes como funciona tu código (escribir el código y no probarlo lo puede hacer hasta un gato caminando sobre el teclado). Prueba, mira si funciona, si encuentras algún problema entonces haz una pregunta especificando qué es lo que te has encontrado.

Comment: @SJuan76      intente corregirlo

Comment: he editado la pregunta

Comment: @SJuan76 he editado la pregunta después de compilar el programa

Comment: He respondido a la pregunta, pero veo que no te molestas en marcar como aceptadas las respuestas que se te dan, y así no es como funciona este sitio. Así que he borrado la respuesta. Cuando hayas marcado como aceptadas las respuestas de tus preguntas anteriores que se lo merezcan, avísame para que la vuelva a poner como visible.

Comment: @SJuan76 entiendo tu molestia pero siento que privar a otros de una respuesta de calidad no es justo, te animo a reconsiderarlo.

Comment: @sjuan76,antes que nada, ante mi ignorancia de cómo funciona el sitio, eso no quiere decir que yo al no "marcar como aceptada una respuesta" tenga ánimo de perjudicar a otros usuarios, al revés, solo tengo palabras de agradecimiento a vuestra labor. Mi cuestión es ¿cómo marco como aceptada una respuesta? le dí a una a una flechita que hay a la izquierda de tu respuesta, ¿es eso?. Gracias

Comment: Las flechitas son para votar las respuestas y preguntas según te parezcan (hacia arriba y hacia abajo), puedes votar preguntas y respuestas de otras personas (una vez tengas la reputación suficiente). Para marcar una respuesta a una de tus preguntas como correcta, hay una marca verde debajo de la flecha hacia abajo ([aquí puedes ver un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89833/como-crear-un-men%c3%ba-de-opciones-en-pascal))

Comment: Tal vez valga la pena [revisar esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54852/error-en-c%c3%b3digo-basico-c-nombredelavariable-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/54921#54921).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varias cosas (realmente, tocaría una pregunta por separado para cada error, pero bueno):

- Líneas 6 y 8. Me parece que te has liado con lo del vector. El vector está definido **dentro de la clase**, en `v_`. Cada vez que crees una instancia de `vector_t`, se creará la memoria para el vector (naturalmente, *tienes que implementar el constructor* y las otras clases definidas).

  Lo que tienes que hacer es definir un único objeto que será el que contenga los datos:

  ```
  vector_t tabla(10);
  ```

  Como he comentado antes, **faltan los métodos para rellenar el contenido del vector interno.** Los tienes que implementar tú (si quieres usar `[]`, tendrás que *sobrecargar el operador []*, lo cual implica definir e implementar un método de la clase de la forma adecuada). O puedes añadir un método `set(int posicion, const T&valor)`

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      tabla.set(i, i*10);
  }
  ```
- Líneas 22 y 32. La declaración de la función está mal, debería ser

  ```
  int vector_t<T>:: bsearch (int i, int d, const T& x){
  ```

  porque la clase es `vector_t<T>`. Como esto falla, no reconoce la función como perteneciente a la clase, así que no sabe que `v_` es un miembro de la clase. Adicionalmente, tienes que declarar el método en la parte `public:`.

  Una vez resuelto esto, te dará un error en la llamada a `bsearch` ya que, como es un método de una instancia, debes indicar de qué instancia se llama al método:

  ```
  central= tabla.bsearch(0, 9, buscado);
  ```