# ¿Como crear un menú de opciones en Pascal?

Tags: windows, pascal, freepascal

soy ***Jose Rangel***.
Soy estudiante de **Ing. Sistemas**, estoy comenzando a ver programación y el primer lenguaje con que hemos iniciado es con *Pascal*.

Como bien dice el titulo, quisiera saber como puedo hacer un menú con dos opciones a elegir. 
Es sobre convertir de *Centigrados* a *Fahrenheit* o viceversa.
el programa no me copila pero no se donde tengo el error.

```
Program Conversor_de_unidades;
uses crt;
var grado, opcion: integer;
begin
clrscr;
write ('introduzca un valor: ');
readln (grado);
write ('seleccione su opcion');
write ('1: Celcius a Fahrenheit');
write('2: Fahrenheit a Celcius');
readln (opcion);
case opcion of
writeln ('C a F: ', (grado+9/5));
readl;
end;
begin
write ('F a C: ', ((grado-32)+9/5));
readln;
end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu codigo tenia 2 problemas, uno era un typo ya que escribiste `readl` en vez de `readln` y el otro era en la sintaxis del [`case of`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Case), la idea es que al usar `case opcion of` tu especifiques que cosa se ejecuta dependiendo de lo ingresado por el usuario, pero en tu codigo faltaba poner `1:` y `2:` que especifica lo que se ejecutara en caso de poner la opcion 1 (que seria `writeln('C a F: ', (grado + 9 / 5))`) y la opcion 2 (que seria `writeln('F a C: ', ((grado - 32) + 9 / 5))`)

El codigo con las correcciones seria:

```
Program Conversor_de_unidades;

uses crt;

var grado, opcion: integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    write('introduzca un valor: ');
    readln(grado);

    writeln('seleccione su opcion');
    writeln('1: Celcius a Fahrenheit');
    writeln('2: Fahrenheit a Celcius');
    readln(opcion);

    case opcion of
        1: writeln('C a F: ', (grado + 9 / 5));
        2: writeln('F a C: ', ((grado - 32) + 9 / 5));
    end;

    readln;
end.
```

Ahora, por otro lado las conversiones que tienes son incorrectas, ya que para pasar de celsius a fahrenheit se usa `(celsius × 9/5) + 32` y para pasar de fahrenheit a celsius se usa `(fahrenheit - 32) x 5/9`, finalmente tu programa quedaria asi:

```
Program Conversor_de_unidades;

uses crt;

var grado, opcion: integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    write('introduzca un valor: ');
    readln(grado);

    writeln('seleccione su opcion');
    writeln('1: Celcius a Fahrenheit');
    writeln('2: Fahrenheit a Celcius');
    readln(opcion);

    case opcion of
        1: writeln('C a F: ', (grado * (9 / 5) + 32));
        2: writeln('F a C: ', ((grado - 32) * (5 / 9)));
    end;

    readln;
end.
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido :D
Tenias muchas dudas de porque no me compilaba.
ahora tengo muy en claro que para el 'Case opcion of'
debo luego escribir la opción con su función.

Answer (score 0):

```
Program Conversor_de_unidades;

uses crt;

var
  grado:real;
  opcion:integer;

begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('Seleccione su opcion');
  writeln('1: Celcius a Fahrenheit');
  writeln('2: Fahrenheit a Celcius');
  write('-> ');
  readln(opcion);
  clrscr;

  if (opcion=1) then
    begin
      write('Introduzca un valor: ');
      readln(grado); clrscr;
      writeln('C a F: ',(grado * (9 / 5) + 32):0:2);
    end;
  if (opcion=2) then
    begin
      write('Introduzca un valor: ');
      readln(grado); clrscr;
      writeln('F a C: ',((grado - 32) * (5 / 9)):0:2)
    end;
  if (opcion<1) or (opcion>2) then
    writeln('Opcion incorrecta');

  readkey;
end.
```

Comment: Por favor edita y explica tu código, pues responder con solo scripts se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Por favor Brayan, las respuestas que solo tienen código son mal vistas por la comunidad, edita la pregunta y explica, al menos, cuál fue su equivocación y cuál sería una posible solución optima... Date una vuelta por [answer] para más información