# Duda la gestión de memoria de c/cpp

Tags: c++, c

Puristas del codigo no me maten al escribir c/cpp por favor,pero como estudiante autodidacta me surge una duda enorme del tiempo de vida de los parametros de las funciones.
Se destruyen automaticamente al terminar la funcion o que pasa?

Comment: El concepto clave ahí es el ámbito (scope) de las variables en un programa. Podrías revisar preguntas relacionadas como [ésta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54852/error-en-c%c3%b3digo-basico-c-nombredelavariable-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: "*Los parámetros de las funciones [...] se destruyen automáticamente al terminar la función*". No, los parámetros son lo que forma parte de la firma de la función, los argumentos son lo que se destruye automáticamente al terminar la función.

Comment: Los parámetros y variables locales se destruyen cuando la función termina su ejecución. Por ejemplo, si llamas a una función A, esta función tendrá una información donde estará guardada en la pila. Esa "información" son los parámetros, variables locales y dirección de retorno de la función, así que cuando la función termine su ejecución, esa "información" será liberada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo cierto es que depende.

La siguiente línea:

```
void miFuncion(int valor1, float valor2);
```

Declara una función que tiene dos parámetros:

```
void miFuncion(int, float);
//             ~~~  ~~~~~ Parámetros
```

En cambio, al implementar la función:

```
void miFuncion(int valor1, float valor2)
{
  std::cout << valor1 << valor2;
}
```

Se crean **dos** variables locales (`valor1` y `valor2`) que se inicializan con los argumentos pasados al llamar a la función:

```
miFuncion(1, 3.5);
//        ~  ~~~ argumentos
```

Pues bien, las variables, como bien hemos dicho, son locales, por lo que su vida está limitada a la propia función. Cuando la ejecución abandone la función las variables locales se destruirán.

```
void miFuncion(int valor1, float valor2)
{
  std::cout << valor1 << valor2;
} // <<--- valor1 y valor2 dejan de existir pasado este punto
```

Sin embargo eso no tiene por qué implicar la pérdida del contenido de dichas variables. Si, usamos referencias o punteros la memoria apuntada por dichas variables sobrevivirá a la llamada a la función.

```
void func(int & var)
{
  var = 10;
}

int variable = 0;
std::cout << variable << '\n'; // imprime 0
func(variable);
std::cout << variable << '\n'; // imprime 10
```

Así pues, el ciclo de vida de los datos dependerá de la naturaleza de los tipos de los parámetros de la siguiente forma:

- Objetos pasados por valor: Se destruyen automáticamente al abandonar la función
- Objetos pasados por referencia/puntero: Sobreviven a la función, lo que destruye aquí es la variable local creada para la ocasión, pero esta variable no controla la vida del objeto original.