# No me funciona unas funciones strcpy cuando las escribo

Tags: string

Estoy haciendo programa que guarde las nota y nombres de 10 alumnos en una matriz,
y muestre las notas de mayor a menor junto con el nombre correcto del alumno. Para eso escribí este código:

```
int main(){

int alumnos;
cout<<"Ingrese el numero de alumnos: "; cin>>alumnos;

cin.ignore(41, '\n'); //Lineas de codigo de ayuda de stack overflow
    cin.clear();

char Nombres[alumnos][41] ={};

for(int i=0;i<alumnos;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno "<<i+1<<": "; cin.getline(Nombres[i],41,'\n');
}

float Notas[alumnos] = {};

for(int i=0;i<alumnos;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese la nota de "<<Nombres[i]<<": "; cin>>Notas[i];
    while((Notas[i]<0)||(Notas[i]>20)){
        cout<<"Las notas tienen que estar dentro del rango 0-20.\n";
        cout<<"Ingrese la nota de "<<Nombres[i]<<": "; cin>>Notas[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

float aux;
char palabra[alumnos][41] = {};

for(int i=0;i<alumnos;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<alumnos;j++){
        if(Notas[j]<Notas[j+1]){
            aux = Notas [j];
            Notas[j] = Notas[j+1];
            Notas[j+1] = aux;
            
            strcpy(palabra[j],Nombres[j]);
            strcpy(Nombres[j],Nombres[j+1]);
            strcpy(Nombres[j+1],palabra[j]);
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<alumnos;i++){
    cout<<Notas[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Pero cuando le doy a compilar me mandá el siguiente error:

```
[Error] 'strcpy' was not declared in this scope
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en código basico c++. "Nombredelavariable" was not declared in this scope](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54852/error-en-c%c3%b3digo-basico-c-nombredelavariable-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: El compilador necesita saber que una función o una variable existe de antemano. Solo tienes que agregar la declaración o los `#include` necesarios.  En este caso,  [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) se encuentra en `string.h`.

Comment: Wow, jajajajaja no me imaginé que sería por eso, jajaja y estuve 15 minutos rompiendome la cabeza por eso. Gracias Mateo